# How to #define hard coded strings when L prefix (Visual C++ compiler) is used?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

How to #define the path L"C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe" for handling wide char

```
#define TASK_MGR "C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe"

KillProcess(TASK_MGR); //this works

HINSTANCE resurrect = ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? Widen the string provided by `TASK_MGR`?

Comment: very bad idea to hard code paths like that

Comment: Why trouble yourself dealing with ansi/unicode conversions? Make your app pure unicode and you have removed a problem. The best solutions are the ones that remove problems.

Comment: Are you really looking for a possibly Visual-C++ specific solution, i.e. don't you want a solution that you can use with any conforming C++ compiler?

Comment: @phresnel currently i was looking for a Visual-C++ specific solution. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @david Thank you David, i am in the process of learning the ansi/unicode stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Visual C++ are you using? This works on Visual Studio 2008:

```
#define PATH L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe";
void func()
{
    const wchar_t *test = PATH;
}
```

If, as Xeo commented, you want to widen the char array, use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx).

Comment: I *think* he wants to widen the already `#define`d string, but it's pretty unclear... Btw, get rid of that `;` in the define.

Comment: You can winden it using another macro, similar to the `_T()` macro

Comment: Thank you Crend, Xeo and Necrolis.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use multiple macros. Fortunately, the Windows headers already define such a macro that widens a string literal when necessary, `TEXT()`, so there's no good reason to write your own.

The following code works fine:

```
#define TASK_MGR "C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe"

KillProcess(TASK_MGR);  // Not sure what KillProcess is or why it takes a narrow
                        // string, regardless of whether Unicode is defined...
                        // The Win32 function is named TerminateProcess.

HINSTANCE resurrect = ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", TEXT(TASK_MGR), NULL, NULL,
                                   SW_MINIMIZE);
```

...well, except for the fact that you hard-coded a path to Task Manager and it's not going to be found at that location on all machines (like mine, for example). But I trust that this is just for example purposes only and you already know well not to hard-code paths.

Comment: @Cody you were right about the hard-coded path being for example purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use string concatenation:

```
#define TASK_MGR "C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe"

/* ... */

HINSTANCE resurrect = ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"" TASK_MGR, NULL, NULL, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Personally, I'd go with

```
static TCHAR const TASK_MGR[] = _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe");
```

The usual rant on hard-coded path names also applies.

Comment: When i use this method i get Compiler Error C2308